# Batch Script Bug - Filename Returns Different then actual Filename

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, filenames

### My Code

I have a really odd bug that I can't for the life of me figure out. Below is a quick snippet of example code:

```
set myFolder=\\myPath\myFolder
set myRootFilename=*myFilenameRoot*.txt

IF NOT EXIST "%myFolder%\%myRootFilename%" GOTO next
FOR /R "%myFolder%" %%F IN (%myRootFilename%) DO (
    set filenameWithExt=%%~nxF
    )
echo %filenameWithExt%
pause

:next
echo doesn't exist
pause
```

### Issue 1 - "Random String"

**Anticipated Results**

*File in the folder:*

> myFilenameRoot_20160422.txt

*Batch echo displays:*

> myFilenameRoot_20160422.txt

**Actual Results**

I've used this code in at least 20 other projects, and it's worked perfect. In this case however, I'm getting something like this:

*File in the folder:*

> myFilenameRoot_20160422.txt

*Batch echo displays:*

> randomSTRING_myFilenameRoot_20140926.txt

I have no clue where the "randomSTRING" is generated, nor where the new date is from?! It's almost like it found another file in the folder (which only has one or two files in it at any time). However, when I manually delete the *myFilenameRoot_20160422.txt* file from the folder... the "IF NOT EXIST" code kicks in.

### Issue 2 - Folder Refresh?

To make matters weirder, I decided to simply remove the wildcard from the beginning of my set string, i.e.:

```
set myRootFilename=myFilenameRoot*.txt
```

This stopped my "Random String" issue. However, now it returned a file with the yesterday's date!

**Anticipated Results**

*File in the folder:*

> myFilenameRoot_20160422.txt

*Batch echo displays:*

> myFilenameRoot_20160422.txt

**Actual Results**

I've used this code in at least 20 other projects, and it's worked perfect. In this case however, I'm getting something like this:

*File in the folder:*

> myFilenameRoot_20160422.txt

*Batch echo displays:*

> myFilenameRoot_20160421.txt

Where did it find this filename? Good question, as I have no clue. So I deleted the file from the folder, and ran the batch again. Yet again, the "IF NOT EXIST" logic kicked in.

So I placed the file back into the folder, ran the batch again - this time the actual results matched the anticipated results... SUCCESS! right?

No... to test the batch one last time, I changed my filename from:

> myFilenameRoot_20160422.txt

to

> myFilenameRoot_20170422.txt

Ran the batch again... but this time it echoed out the old result:

> myFilenameRoot_20160422.txt

Rinse and repeat above troubleshooting steps countless times. I can't figure out where / why it is finding these alternative file names! Does anyone have any clue what is happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the code you showed part of a bigger script (inside another `for` or `if`)?

Comment: @Stephan - there is a bunch more to the script, but no - the code above is not nested within any of it.

Comment: You know that `for /R` searches a directory recursively? if you do not want that, change it to `FOR %%F IN ("%myFolder%\%myRootFilename%") DO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @aschipfl for the answer in the comments. I simply had to adjust the FOR loop...

**Original Broken Code:**

```
FOR /R "%myFolder%" %%F IN (%myRootFilename%) DO ()
```

**New, Functional Code:**

```
FOR %%F IN ("%myFolder%\%myRootFilename%") DO ()
```